# how to calculate R1 (lexical richness index) in R?

Tags: r, list, function, text-mining, quanteda

Hi I need to write a function to calculate R1  which is defined as follows :

R1 = 1 - ( F(h) - h*h/2N) )

where N is the number of tokens, h is the Hirsch point, and F(h) is the cumulative relative frequencies up to that point. Using `quanteda` package I managed to calculate the Hirsch point

```
 a <- c("The truck driver whose runaway vehicle rolled into the path of an express train and caused one of Taiwan’s worst ever rail disasters has made a tearful public apology.", "The United States is committed to advancing prosperity, security, and freedom for both Israelis and Palestinians in tangible ways in the immediate term, which is important in its own right, but also as a means to advance towards a negotiated two-state solution.")
a1 <- c("The 49-year-old is part of a team who inspects the east coast rail line for landslides and other risks.", "We believe that this UN agency for so-called refugees should not exist in its current format.")
a2 <- c("His statement comes amid an ongoing investigation into the crash, with authorities saying the train driver likely had as little as 10 seconds to react to the obstruction.", " The US president accused Palestinians of lacking “appreciation or respect.", "To create my data I had to chunk each text in an increasing manner.", "Therefore, the input is a list of chunked texts within another list.")
a3 <- c("We plan to restart US economic, development, and humanitarian assistance for the Palestinian people,” the secretary of state, Antony Blinken, said in a statement.", "The cuts were decried as catastrophic for Palestinians’ ability to provide basic healthcare, schooling, and sanitation, including by prominent Israeli establishment figures.","After Donald Trump’s row with the Palestinian leadership, President Joe Biden has sought to restart Washington’s flailing efforts to push for a two-state resolution for the Israel-Palestinian crisis, and restoring the aid is part of that.")
txt <-list(a,a1,a2,a3)

    
library(quanteda)
DFMs <- lapply(txt, dfm)
txt_freq <- function(x) textstat_frequency(x, groups = docnames(x), ties_method = "first")
Fs <- lapply(DFMs, txt_freq)

get_h_point <- function(DATA) {
  fn_interp <- approxfun(DATA$rank, DATA$frequency)
  fn_root <- function(x) fn_interp(x) - x
  uniroot(fn_root, range(DATA$rank))$root
}

s_p <- function(x){split(x,x$group)}  
tstat_by <- lapply(Fs, s_p)
h_values <-lapply(tstat_by, vapply, get_h_point, double(1))
```

To calculate F(h)—the cumulative relative frequencies up to h_point— to put in R1, I need two values; one of them needs to be from `Fs$rank` and the other must be from `h_values`. Consider the first original texts (`tstat_by[[1]]`, `tstat_by[[2]]`, and `tstat_by[[3]]`) and their respective h_values(`h_values[[1]]`, `h_values[[2]]`, and `h_values[[3]]`):

```
fh_txt1 <- tail(prop.table(cumsum(tstat_by[[1]][["text1"]]$rank:h_values[[1]][["text1"]])), n=1)
fh_txt2 <-tail(prop.table(cumsum(tstat_by[[1]][["text2"]]$rank:h_values[[1]][["text2"]])), n=1)
...

tail(prop.table(cumsum(tstat_by[[4]][["text2"]]$rank:h_values[[4]][["text2"]])), n=1)
[1] 1
tail(prop.table(cumsum(tstat_by[[4]][["text3"]]$rank:h_values[[4]][["text3"]])), n=1)
[1] 0.75
```

As you can see, the grouping is the same— docnames for each chunk of the original character vectors are the same (text1, text2, text3, etc.). my question is how to write a function for fh_txt(s) so that using lapply can be an option to calculate F(h) for R1.

Please note that the goal is to write a function to calculate R1, and what I`ve put here is what has been done in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your inputs below, and used the `groups` argument in `textstat_frequency()` instead of your approach to creating lists of dfm objects.

```r
a <- c("The truck driver whose runaway vehicle rolled into the path of an express train and caused one of Taiwan’s worst ever rail disasters has made a tearful public apology.")
a1 <- c("The 49-year-old is part of a team who inspects the east coast rail line for landslides and other risks.")
a2 <- c("His statement comes amid an ongoing investigation into the crash, with authorities saying the train driver likely had as little as 10 seconds to react to the obstruction.")

library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.0.0
## Unicode version: 10.0
## ICU version: 61.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
dfmat <- c(a, a1, a2) %>%
  tokens() %>%
  dfm()

tstat <- quanteda.textstats::textstat_frequency(dfmat, groups = docnames(dfmat), ties = "first")
tstat_by <- split(tstat, tstat$group)

get_h_point <- function(DATA) {
  fn_interp <- approxfun(DATA$rank, DATA$frequency)
  fn_root <- function(x) fn_interp(x) - x
  uniroot(fn_root, range(DATA$rank))$root
}
h_values <- vapply(tstat_by, get_h_point, double(1))
h_values
##    text1    text2    text3 
## 2.000014 1.500000 2.000024

tstat_by <- lapply(
  names(tstat_by),
  function(x) subset(tstat_by[[x]], cumsum(rank) <= h_values[[x]])
)

do.call(rbind, tstat_by)
##    feature frequency rank docfreq group
## 1      the         2    1       1 text1
## 29     the         2    1       1 text2
## 48     the         3    1       1 text3
```

You didn't specify what you wanted for output, but with this result, you should be able to compute your own either on the list using `lapply()`, or on the combined data.frame using for instance **dplyr**.

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: tnx for the time you spent on this. you added the grouping argument for the texts which is helpful. however, I need to calculate F(h)— cumulative relative frequency— up to h point for each text. by the way, the actual data I have is a list of texts and I need a function. I`ve modified the codes. Have a look. –